# AC Power Splitter and Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, cables, coax, split

Is there a charging cable which splits into two?
One of the split cable will have DC 12v 3a with a male coaxial 5.5mm x 9.5mm
The other split cable will have DC 5v 3a with a USB Micro.

Does this exist? If so, where can I buy one?
If it doesn't exist, how can I make one?

Comment: Hi, questions about electrical product recommendation are [off-topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please take a [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Title says AC but question says DC. A "charging cable" can't do voltage regulation. What goes in one end comes out the other.

Answer (score 0):

probably the easiest way to make that would be to take a desktop 12V 5A power supply and splice a 5A buck module into the output cord

Sellers of cheap buck modules tend to over-estimate their capability by a bit - that's why I reccomend a "5A" modules to suppyk your "3A" need.  a search for "XL4015 5A" should get you some examples of the type of module I mean. cost is about $1 on aliexpress or banggood

If you can live with a lower power level a hard drive testing power supply can typically do 12V2A and 5V2A simultaneously